# Input should stop after asking 20 names and grades or when the user hits 'Enter' with no input

Tags: assembly, x86, irvine32

The program is in Assembly language [MASM] and based on *Chapter 5* of **Irvine, Kip. Assembly Language for x86 Processors, Seventh Edition. Pearson Education, 2015**.
The cmp & je instruction for the name is not working when I try to input no name in the prompt. If pressed enter it displays "Press any key to continue" but also some junk below it.

```
    TITLE MASM Template      (main.asm)

INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

NAMEGRADE STRUCT                            ;structure storing the name & grade
    personName BYTE 26 DUP (?)
    personGrade BYTE 2 DUP (?)
NAMEGRADE ENDS

.data
str1 BYTE "Please enter student's name",0dh,0ah,0   ;Prompt1
str2 BYTE "Please enter ",0                         ;Prompt2
str3 BYTE "'s grade",0dh,0ah,0                      ;Prompt3

CounterOne BYTE 00H                                 ;counter 1 used for inputting array
CounterTwo BYTE 00H                                 ;counter 2 used for outputting array
MyTable NAMEGRADE 20 DUP (<>)                       ;table storing the arrays with structure initialized variables

personName BYTE 26 DUP (?)                          ;Name unitnitialized currently
.code
main PROC

Startover:                      ;Label used for jumping back after successful output and after 1 successful array input 
    call Clrscr                 ;Clears the screen

    mov edx, OFFSET str1    
    call WriteString            ;Prompt1 diplayed
    mov  edx,OFFSET personName
    mov  ecx,26                 ;26 characters allowed for the name
    call ReadString             ;inputs name

    cmp personName, 0       ;No name entered, then display table else exit
    je ArrayOut 


    mov eax,SIZEOF NAMEGRADE                    ;Calculate offset in structure
    mul CounterOne                              ;sets counter
    mov edi,eax
    mov esi, OFFSET personName                  ;Offset of the source for the move
    add edi, OFFSET MyTable.personName          ;adds it to the table elements
    mov ecx, SIZEOF personName                  ;Number of characters to move    
    rep movsb


;Input data into array
ArrayWork:                          ;label that has the 20 strings for array
    inc CounterOne                  ;increments counter 
    cmp CounterOne, 20              ;checks if counter is less than or equal to 20
    jbe ArrayOut                    ;once 20 names & grades entered, display them

;Output of table being calculated 
ArrayOut:
    call clrscr
    mov esi,0
    mov row, 3
ArrayLoop:
    mov dh, row
    mov dl, 5                       ;assigns name in column 5
    call Gotoxy                     ;locate cursor 
    mov eax, SIZEOF NAMEGRADE
    mul CounterTwo
    mov esi, eax
    lea  edx, (MyTable[esi]).personName 

    ;cmp edx, 0                     ;No name then exit
    ;je ProgramEnds

    call WriteString                ;Displays the student's name 

;Table output must be set & looped
    inc CounterTwo
    inc row
    mov al, CounterOne   
    cmp CounterTwo, al  
    jne ArrayLoop

;The WaitMsg part
Waiting:
 mov dh,24  ;or use row instead of 24
 mov dl,1
 call Gotoxy
 mov eax, white + (black * 16)  ;sets the color to WaitMsg
 call SetTextColor
 call WaitMsg                   ;displays Press any key to continue
 call Clrscr
 jmp Startover                  ;Jumps to restart the program after successful output

ProgramEnds:                   ;Program must exit if no name entered
 exit
main ENDP

END main     ;end of program
```

I expected the output just to be "Press any key to continue" if no name is entered. Compiled using Visual Studio 2017
Debugging looks like:

```
 Press any key to continue...
                                ABCDEF                                                                                       CDEF
x                           offset
     ffset                      ------------
     ----------
       EAX=                     =
       ESI=                     =
       EIP=
       ZF=
                               verflow>
     rflow>                     

â                               sK'MtM&HìH(PæP!IäI"QvQ$GwG#OuO-RÆR.SôSkNÉNmJÄJzààà{ååå╜é╗
â    'MtM&HìH(PæP!IäI"QvQ$GwG#OuuO-RÆR.SôSkNÉNmJÄJzààà{ååå╜é╗
â    -RÆR.SôSkNÉNmJÄJzààà{ååå╜é╗
â    ╗                          continue...
     ntinue...
                                ame
     e
     (saved ebp) <--- ebp       ed register)
      register)                 e)
                                sp
                                lid
     d
```

What's the junk after Press any key to continue?

Comment: If anyone needs more clarification I can show you the entire program.

Comment: `ReadString` returns the length in `eax`. It's simpler to just check that. If you insist on checking `personName` make sure you are checking a single byte not a dword, e.g. try `cmp byte ptr [personName], 0` or similar.

Comment: How do you know `cmp/je` is "not working"?  Did you single step with a debugger and find that the branch is not taken when ReadString produces a zero-length output string?  (BTW, checking the return value of [ReadString](http://programming.msjc.edu/asm/help/index.html?page=source%2Firvinelib%2Freadstring.htm) would be more efficient than checking the first byte of memory, but both are correct assuming `personName` was declared with `db`.) This is not a [mcve], because without seeing the printing code or using a debugger to look for buffer overflows, the "also some junk" tells us nothing useful

Comment: Hi Peter, when pressed enter with no name its displaying:  "Press any key to continue...
                                ABCDEF                                                                                     CDEF   x                           offset
     ffset                      ------------
     ----------
       EAX=                     =
       ESI=                     =
       EIP=
       ZF=
                               verflow>
     rflow>                     
â                               sK'MtM&HìH(PæP!IäI"QvQ$GwG#OuO-RÆR.SôSkNÉNmJÄJzààà{ååå╜é╗

Comment: its declared as: personName BYTE 26 DUP (?)

Comment: For people to get notified of your replies, use an @ sign, like @user11187163.  Also, comments can't have formatting, so edit your question with your debugger findings

Comment: `mov  ecx,26` is a bug.  You need to pass `SIZEOF personName - 1` because as the ReadString doc points out, that size *doesn't* include space for the terminating 0.  If the user types in a max-length string, the terminating 0 won't be part of the 26 bytes you copy around.  That's probably separate from the bug you're asking about, though: since it is declared with `BYTE`, your `cmp` should work and correctly detect Enter on an empty line.  So the bug is somewhere else in your big piece of code.  Simplify down to a more minimal [mcve] that doesn't do much else besides wait for enter.

Comment: @PeterCordes well then maybe in the label ArrayOut? It takes the names and grades and then outputs into the table.

Comment: That would be the obvious place to start debugging, yes.  Check that `edx` really does point to a 0-terminated string right before the `call WriteString`.  Also, in ArrayWork, the `jbe ArrayOut` is probably a bug, because it jumps to the same place it falls through to, so it doesn't matter what the compare result was.

Comment: @PeterCordes looks like it still crashes on cmp edx,0. There is a limit to the number of names and grades asked for input hence I cmp them and if below or equal to 20 then display them using ArrayOut.

Comment: @Jester yes I am comparing bytes not dw or db.

Comment: `edx` will never be a NULL pointer; you're using LEA to index into a static array.  What you might want to check for is an empty *string*, i.e. `cmp byte ptr [edx], 0`.  But that's a separate piece of code from `cmp CounterOne, 20 / jbe ArrayOut`.  For that, what will be the next instruction if the branch is not taken, so execution falls through the branch?  And what will be the next instruction if the branch *is* taken?  Anyway, single-step with your debugger and see figure out when "garbage" is printed; look at register values to see if you've gone too many loop iterations or what.

Comment: doing cmp byte ptr [edx], 0 actually worked and removed those junk files and just prints the WaitMsg. Thanks for helping me out @PeterCordes really appreciate it